# Consecutive commands using Ubuntu makefile to compile latex project

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to use a Makefile to create a LaTeX project.  I can't seem to get the order of operations to work properly

```
DISSERTATION = Dissertation
TEX = pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape 
BIBTOOL = biber
OPEN = open -a Skim.app
RESOURCES = ${DISSERTATION}.pdf

###### Targets #####

# compile the LaTeX document
tex:
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}

# create bibliography file for LaTeX
bib:
    ${BIBTOOL} ${DISSERTATION}

# Order of operations (LaTeX --> biber -->  LaTeX --> LaTeX)
order: tex bib tex tex

# Second attempt
file:
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}
    ${BIBTOOL} ${DISSERTATION}
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}

clean:  
    rm -rf auto *_minted-* *.log *.aux *.synctex.gz *.out *.toc *.run *.bcf *.lof *.lot *.tdo *.run.xml *.pdf *.bbl *.blg
    
release:
    rm -rf Release
    mkdir Release
    cp *.pdf Release
    make clean
```

In terminal I currently type `make order` and it only compiles the tex file once and quits.  It doesn't call biber to create the citations used to re-order the references.

I also tried the command `make file` which is just putting them in order and it does the same thing.  Just quits after the first command `${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}`.

Here is the associated terminal error message:

```
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
ist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ams
fonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy
10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmr.pfb></u
sr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathpazo/fplmri.pfb></usr/share/
texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/palatino/uplb8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/urw/palatino/uplr8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/urw/palatino/uplri8a.pfb>
Output written on Dissertation.pdf (70 pages, 9452807 bytes).
SyncTeX written on Dissertation.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Dissertation.log.
make: *** [Makefile:14: tex] Error 1
```

However, when I execute the commands separately this does work!  i.e. `make tex` --> `make bib` --> `make tex` --> `make tex`.

The commands `make release` and `make clean` work perfectly.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.  With my limited knowledge of Linux, I'm stumped.  If anyone knows, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: There are some fundamental problems with how your Makefile is written, but even if we were to fix those issues it can still be tricky to get a Makefile right for LaTeX projects because of the need to run multiple passes of certain commands. I think you might want to read through the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40738/how-to-properly-make-a-latex-project) which explore all this in much more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I have my Makefile updated using one of the references from their answers.  Hopefully, I have it written correctly.  I'll post it as an answer to this question.  If you have any suggestions on how to make it written correctly, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated Makefile that seems to solve the issue I mentioned above.  I had to download ***latexmk*** as the work around for the multiple compile steps to get the citations in the correct order.

```
# Linux Makefile to create a final pdf of the project

# Variables
FILE = Dissertation

# PDF LaTeX specific
PDFLATEX = "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 --shell-escape"

# You want latexmk to *always* run, because make does not have all the info.
# Also, include non-file targets in .PHONY so they are run regardless of any
# file of the given name existing.
.PHONY: ${FILE}.pdf all clean

# The first rule in a Makefile is the one executed by default ("make"). It
# should always be the "all" rule, so that "make" and "make all" are identical.
all: ${FILE}.pdf

# CUSTOM BUILD RULES

# In case you didn't know, '$@' is a variable holding the name of the target,
# and '$<' is a variable holding the (first) dependency of a rule.
# "raw2tex" and "dat2tex" are just placeholders for whatever custom steps
# you might have.

%.tex: %.raw
    ./raw2tex $< > $@

%.tex: %.dat
    ./dat2tex $< > $@

# MAIN LATEXMK RULE

# -pdf tells latexmk to generate PDF directly (instead of DVI).
# -pdflatex="" tells latexmk to call a specific backend with specific options.
# -use-make tells latexmk to call make for generating missing files.

# -interaction=nonstopmode keeps the pdflatex backend from stopping at a
# missing file reference and interactively asking you for an alternative.

# --shell-escape allows for *minted to run code highlighting

# -f forces latexmk to run until compiling has been complete regardless of
#  cross referencing (i.e. it continues to run until references are in the
#  correct location)

${FILE}.pdf: ${FILE}.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=${PDFLATEX} -f -use-make ${FILE}.tex

# Clean up unnecessary files
clean:
    latexmk -C
    # specific to latexmk

clear:  
    rm -rf auto *_minted-* *.log *.aux *.synctex.gz *.out *.toc *.run *.bcf *.lof *.lot *.tdo *.run.xml *.pdf *.bbl *.blg

release:
    rm -rf Release
    mkdir Release
    cp *.pdf Release
    make clear
    make clean
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer should be strictly an answer. `%.pdf: %.tex` specifies a rule for making a `pdf` file out of a `tex` file where the stem can be anything. In the recipe, `$*` expands to the stem, and `$@` expands to the target you are making, etc; see the Make documentation for details.

Comment: I'll edit that so I don't end with a question.  Thank you!

Comment: So that recipe should be `%.pdf: %.tex` (newline) (tab) `latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=${PDFLATEX} -f -use-make $<` and it tells Make how to make `foo.pdf` from `foo.tex`, `bar.pdf` from `bar.tex`, etc. This rule is not `.PHONY` so you should remove that.